# Re-arrage JSON values from existing values

Tags: javascript, dictionary, reduce

The JSON provided is kind of unstructured and doesn't meet many of my 
   requirements. I have tried this many ways but does take a very long time 
   when I provide 100,000 records

**Implemented Code**

```
for (var f in stack.data) {
  var field = new Object();
  for (var o in stack.data[f]['field_values']) {
    field[stack.data[f]['field_values'][o]['field_name']] = stack.data[f]['field_values'][o]['value'];
  }
  stack.data[f]['field_values'] = field;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(stack, null, 2));
```

**Input JSON:**

```
var stack = {
  "data": [{
    "id": 950888888073,
    "name": "www.stackoverflow.com",

    "field_values": [{
        "field_name": "Newsletter?",
        "value": true
      },
      {
        "field_name": "Parent",
        "value": 950888661
      },
      {
        "field_name": "Birthday",
        "value": "2018-04-29"
      },
      {
        "field_name": "Related matter",
        "value": 1055396205
      },
      {
        "field_name": "Referral",
        "value": "Don Ho"
      },
      {
        "field_name": "Spouse",
        "value": "Wo Fat"
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
{
  "data": [
  {
  "id": 950888888073,
  "name": "www.stackoverflow.com",
  "field_values": {
    "Newsletter?": true,
    "Parent": "Gigi Hallow",
    "Birthday": "2018-04-29",
    "Related": "2012-00121-Sass",
    "Referral": "Don Ho",
    "Spouse": "Wo Fat"
  }
```

Sometimes "field_values can be empty. Need to check them as well

```
     {
      "id": 950821118875,
      "name": "www.google.com",
      "field_values": [],
}
```

This is mostly re-arranging the values. Here values becomes keys. There should actually be one liner to handle this, but i am run out of options.

Hope the question is clear

Comment: did you have a question?

Comment: Doing anything 100K times in JavaScript will be slow.

Comment: Should `custom_field_values` in the last example be `field_values`?

Comment: Just updated it...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It would probably help to declare a variable to hold the array element, rather than doing 4 levels of indexing every time through the loop. You can also use destructuring to extract the properties of the object.

And use `{}` rather than `new Object`.

Even if this doesn't improve performance, it makes the code easier to read.

```js
var stack = {
  "data": [{
    "id": 950888888073,
    "name": "www.stackoverflow.com",

    "field_values": [{
        "field_name": "Newsletter?",
        "value": true
      },
      {
        "field_name": "Parent",
        "value": 950888661
      },
      {
        "field_name": "Birthday",
        "value": "2018-04-29"
      },
      {
        "field_name": "Related matter",
        "value": 1055396205
      },
      {
        "field_name": "Referral",
        "value": "Don Ho"
      },
      {
        "field_name": "Spouse",
        "value": "Wo Fat"
      }
    ]
  }]
}

for (var f in stack.data) {
  const field = {};
  const fobj = stack.data[f];
  for (var o in fobj.field_values) {
    const {field_name, value} = fobj.field_values[o];
    field[field_name] = value;
  }
  fobj.field_values = field;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(stack, null, 2));
```